# Unicode for latex symbol \varoiint

Tags: unicode, latex

Unicode for latex symbol \varoiint, I got the unicode 222F but it's not correct

```
unicode 222F
```

[image]

```
My requirement is
```

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like the same symbol just in a different font.

Comment: You will need to find a font that renders that character how you would like.

Comment: @一二三 True! See also page 56 of [this manual](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780321773265/samplepages/0321773268.pdf).